# [moveIt! ]catkin_package() include dir 'include/eigen3' does not exist relative to

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:296 (message):   catkin_package() include dir 'include/eigen3' does not exist relative to   '/home//moveIt_ws/src/moveit/moveit_kinematics'

environment: ROS indigo ubuntu14.04   moveIt! 0.7.8
build from source
fix package.xml and CMakeLists.txt in moveit/moveit_kinematics/

https://github.com/YuehChuan/moveit/commit/c3e16461d1541846bc7171d4bdf2167ba23e6922

here are my history
https://hackmd.io/s/BJAiRmxje#

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256794/%5Bmoveit!-%5Dcatkin_package()-include-dir-%27include/eigen3%27-does-not-exist-relative-to/) by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

follow these
https://github.com/YuehChuan/moveit/commit/c3e16461d1541846bc7171d4bdf2167ba23e6922

---

Originally posted by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) with karma: 36 on 2017-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0